# Jest + IntelliJ (IDEA) => ERROR: Zone is needed for the async() test helper but could not be found

Tags: angular, intellij-idea, jestjs, webstorm

When I run Jest-Unit tests on Angular-Libs from the command-line, they work fine. When I run them from IntelliJ (version 2019.1) on individual tests, they work only as long as I don't use async().

This is strange because my angular.json contains this:

```
    "auth": {
      "root": "libs/auth",
      "sourceRoot": "libs/auth/src",
      "projectType": "library",
      "prefix": "auth",
      "architect": {
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "libs/auth/tsconfig.lib.json",
              "libs/auth/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": ["**/node_modules/**"]
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@nrwl/builders:jest",
          "options": {
            "jestConfig": "libs/auth/jest.config.js",
            "tsConfig": "libs/auth/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "setupFile": "libs/auth/src/test-setup.ts"
          }
        }
      },
      "schematics": {
        "@nrwl/schematics:component": {
          "styleext": "scss"
        }
      }
    },
```

And in `test-setup.ts` (inside the lib) there is `import 'jest-preset-angular';` included, which does:

```
require('core-js/es6/reflect'); 
require('core-js/es7/reflect'); 
require('zone.js/dist/zone.js');    
require('zone.js/dist/proxy.js');   
require('zone.js/dist/sync-test');  
require('zone.js/dist/async-test'); 
require('zone.js/dist/fake-async-test');    
require('./zone-patch');
```

during setup.

So why is IntelliJ not picking the config from angular.json correctly, like the command-line does? Can I fix this in "Edit configurations..." somehow?

EDIT: here is the repo: https://github.com/philly-vanilly/ng-reddit

Comment: please can you share a sample project that can be used to recreate the issue?

Comment: @lena I've added the link to the repo. To reproduce just try to execute over IDE any test that has a beforeEach with an async()

Comment: weird... I can't recreate the issue using your project. I get different errors, depending on spec/working directory/jest package selected, but none of them looks similar. I particular, when running Jest for `apps/web/src/app/app.component.spec.ts` I get the same error as reported when running `ng test` - `Action type "[Auth] UserLoginCall" is not unique"`

Comment: please can you attach a screenshot of your run configuration?

Comment: I also have this problem (but with Mocha).  When I copy and paste what IntelliJ says it is running in a terminal it runs fine.  This is `/usr/local/opt/node@10/bin/node /Users/bbos/dev/dhs/translate/board/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha -r ts-node/register --timeout 5000 --ui bdd --reporter "/Users/bbos/Library/Application Support/IntelliJIdea2019.1/NodeJS/js/mocha-intellij/lib/mochaIntellijReporter.js" client/src/**/*.spec.ts`

Comment: **My bad** - I was running this on the client as can been seen.  The angular client uses `ng test` that pulls in config from the `angular.json` and via this there is a reference to `zone.js`.

Comment: I am also experiencing this error.  Has anyone had any luck in getting tests to run in intellij with jest?

Comment: Same problem here :-(

Comment: Having the same issue with Angular 8, Jest and IntelliJ. Any fix or solution?